# Why doesn't storage for a duplicate empty base overlap with a vtable pointer?

Tags: c++

Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct A {};
    struct B : A {};
    struct C : A, B {};

    std::cout << sizeof(A) << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << sizeof(B) << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << sizeof(C) << '\n'; // 2, because of a duplicate base

    struct E : A {virtual ~E() {}};
    struct F : A, B {virtual ~F() {}};

    std::cout << sizeof(E) << '\n'; // 8, the base overlaps the vtable pointer
    std::cout << sizeof(F) << '\n'; // 16, but why?
}
```

<sup>[(run on godbolt)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++struct+A+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++struct+B+:+A+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++struct+C+:+A,+B+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+sizeof(A)+%3C%3C+!'%5Cn!'%3B+//+1%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+sizeof(B)+%3C%3C+!'%5Cn!'%3B+//+1%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+sizeof(C)+%3C%3C+!'%5Cn!'%3B+//+2,+because+of+a+duplicate+base%0A%0A++++struct+E+:+A+%7Bvirtual+~E()+%7B%7D%7D%3B%0A++++struct+F+:+A,+B+%7Bvirtual+~F()+%7B%7D%7D%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+sizeof(E)+%3C%3C+!'%5Cn!'%3B+//+8,+the+base+overlaps+the+vtable+pointer%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+sizeof(F)+%3C%3C+!'%5Cn!'%3B+//+16,+but+why%3F%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50.40904944965782,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:49.590950550342185,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:9,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+9.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:49.590950550342185,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)</sup>

Here you can see that for `struct E` the empty base class (which is 1 byte large) uses the same storage as the vtable pointer, as expected.

But for `struct F`, which has a duplicate empty base, this doesn't happen. What causes this?

I get the same result on GCC, Clang, and MSVC. The results above are for x64, so `sizeof(void *) == 8`.

---

Interestingly, for `struct G : A, B {void *ptr;};` GCC and Clang do perform EBO (the size is 8), but MSVC doesn't (the size is 16).

Comment: Strangely, by inheriting from `C` (which inherit from `A`, `B`) you get different result than inheriting form `A` and `B` directly

Comment: Interesting. I suspect it's just a missed optimization opportunity. The other `A` could theoretically occupy another byte of the first 8. Good question.

Comment: I've enjoyed researching this one. Thanks for the question and the link. I'm not sure I have an answer and so will simply comment. Could it be that this arises from the ambiguity introduced from the derivation of `C` and `F`? After all, `2 * sizeof(void*) == 16` on x86_64 as you've said. The compiler can't fully optimize (as Story Teller said) and so doesn't.

Comment: StoryTeller, not true. The 8 bytes have a purpose. There is no "overlap" or "occupy" going on here. Once you give the structure a size, the default 1 byte that is needed to make the struct addressable is no longer needed and dropped. The example here creates an invalid class structure as A is ambiguous. My guess is, the compilers are attempting to deal with this.

Comment: It is normal that you get the same result on gcc and clang, since they both follow the itanium ABI. And if this is the case I think, when defining the ABI, they were afraid the layout algorithm might become too expensive, so they took some shortcuts (aka pessimizations).

Comment: @RianQuinn A duplicate base doesn't make a structure invalid.

Comment: https://medium.com/free-code-camp/multiple-inheritance-in-c-and-the-diamond-problem-7c12a9ddbbec

Comment: Try to compile: std::cout << (void *)static_cast<A*>(&f). You will get an error because the compiler cannot resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: @RianQuinn inheriting from the same class multiple times via different "paths" is perfectly valid in C++. If you want to create a diamond structure, i.e. have the base class only once, you have to use virtual inheritance. But if you don't want a diamond and having a duplicate base class is no issue for you, then this is no issue for the language either. OP's code only produces a warning, saying that the second `A`, inherited via `B`, cannot cannot be accessed. That is fine. Only if you actually do try to access it, as in your example, you get an error.

Comment: @RianQuinn Having a diamond inheritance without `virtual` if often undesirable, but it doesn't make a class invalid. *"compiler cannot resolve the ambiguity"* First, let's differentiate between *duplicated* bases and *inaccessible* (because of an ambiguity) bases. In my code, `A` is both duplicated an inaccessible. The warning Clang gives refers to it being inaccessible. By [adding even more classes](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xtp5DD) you can resolve the ambiguity and make it accessible via a sequence of casts (which removes the warning).

Comment: I updated my example below. If you remove the ambiguity you still have the issue of of the class being larger than needed. Your example IMO, is invalid C++ as this does not compile. If you remove the ambiguity, it is valid C++, and you are right, that there is a missed oppurtunity for optimizations. IMO, the example should be updated to reflect your point without the need for ambiguity as you explain above.

Comment: You can figure out where each base is using something like `cout << (B*)(F*)0`, I think this will help understand it better.

Comment: I concede here. Looking into this further (did a vtable dump and compared addresses to a statically compiled, non-pie binary), and the contents of the vtable do not make much sense to me. Looking into it further (this all assumes the ambiguity is removed BTW), I cannot explain why C is size 2 either (I am not sure I buy the duplicate base explaintaion). I would argue that no optimization is likely needed as this should never be done in the first place (even with the ambiguity removed)... but this question has definitely stumped me.

Comment: For G: the virtual case is more similar to: `struct L {void*ptr;};struct H : L, A, B {};` (size 16). The order is important, `A,B,L` would give size 8.

Answer (score 4):

Because the compiler adds one byte padding after struct A

F {vptr(8) + 0 members from A + 1 padding (because A is empty)+0 from b} = 9
then the compiler add 7 bytes padding to align storage of the struct;

E {vptr(8) + 0 members for A} = 8 No padding required

from Microsoft

> Every data object has an alignment-requirement. For structures, the
>   requirement is the largest of its members. Every object is allocated
>   an offset so that offset % alignment-requirement == 0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/storage-and-alignment-of-structures?view=vs-2019

**EDIT:**

here is my demo:

```
int main()
{
    C c;
    A* a = &c;
    B* b = &c;

    std::cout << sizeof(A) << " " << a << '\n'; 
    std::cout << sizeof(B) << " " << b << '\n'; 
    std::cout << sizeof(C) << " " << &c << '\n'; 

    E e;
    a = &e;
    std::cout << sizeof(E) <<" " << &e << " " << a << '\n'; 

    F f;
    a = &f;
    b = &f;
    std::cout << sizeof(F) << " " << &f << " " << a << " " << b << '\n';

}
```

output:

```
1 0000007A45B7FBB4
1 0000007A45B7FBB5
1 0000007A45B7FBB4
8 0000007A45B7FC18 0000007A45B7FC20
16 0000007A45B7FC38 0000007A45B7FC40 0000007A45B7FC41
```

as you can see a & b never overlaps with each other and with vptr on multiple inheritance each has its own pointer value

note compiled by VC2019 x64 build

Comment: I don't think this is how it works. Even though `A` has no members, it still occupies 1 byte (which can be shared with an other object). In `E`, `A` is not located after the vptr; it overlaps the first byte of vptr. (Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NmF8v7); I've modified the code slightly to make `A` accessible.). Same happens for the first `A` in `F`. Since `A` (and `B`) can be placed on top of the vptr, I'm not sure why it doesn't happen for `B`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but this is what happened check test code

Comment: Aha, so MSVC behaves differently from GCC/Clang here; it's not smart enough to put `A` on top of the vptr. It can explain why the output is 16 on MSVC, but I'm not sure what's going on with GCC & Clang.